# Sequence Converging Not Lebesgue integrable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let f be a function on [0,1] that is continuous on (0,1]. Show that it is possible  for the sequence $\{\int_{[1/n,1]}f\}$ to converge and yet $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable over [0,1]. Can this happen if $f$ is nonnegative?

So we just need to show that this is possible for one such sequence with a given f that meets this criteria. Is there any function that satisfies this?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$f(x) =\lceil 1/x \rceil \sin (2 \lfloor 1/x \rfloor\lceil 1/x \rceil\pi x)$$ where $\lfloor 1/x \rfloor$ means the highest integer less than than or equal to $1/x$ and $\lceil 1/x \rceil$ means the lowest integer greater than or equal to $1/x$.

$f(x)$ is continuous because at all points at which $\lfloor 1/x \rfloor$ and  $\lceil 1/x \rceil$ are discontinuous, namely at all $x = 1/n$ for $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$, the argument of the sine is a multiple of $2\pi$ on either side of the discontinuity, so
$f(x)$ approaches zero on both sides of $x = 1/n$.

For all $n > 1 : n\in \Bbb{Z}$,
$$
\int_{1/n}^1 f(x) dx = \sum_{k=2}^n k\int_{1/k}^{1/(k-1)}\sin\left[2k(k-1)\pi x\right] dx 
$$
and making the substitution $t = k(k-1) x$ the integral becomes
$$
\int_{1/n}^1 f(x) dx = \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k-1}\int_{t=k-1}^{k}\sin(2\pi t)dt 
=\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k-1} [0]
$$
so the sequence of integrals converges.

Yet $f(x)$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$ since
$$
\int_{0}^1 |f(x)| dx = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}
\int_{1/n}^1 |f(x)| dx = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k-1}\int_{t=k-1}^{k}|\sin(2\pi t)|dt 
=\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k-1} [\frac{2}{\pi}]
$$
and the sum on the right diverges.